# How to read attributes from tags in XML to HTML

Tags: html, xml, href

Im going to list some items from an xml file that looks like this:

```
<artist href="spotify:artist:1gR0gsQYfi6joyO1dlp76N">
<name>Justice</name>
<popularity>0.59872</popularity>
</artist>
```

It is requested from http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/artist?q=justice

My code looks like this:

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("artist");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 
document.write("<tr><td>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

document.write("</td><td>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("popularity")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

document.write("</td><td>");
document.write(x[i].HOW DO I GET THE SPOTIFY URI);

document.write("</td></tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
```

Everything works fine, except that I dont know how to get the spotify URL into a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`x[i].getAttribute('href')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute).

Comment: Thats just the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're using JavaScript, but have you considered using XSLT?

If you are merely converting XML to HTML, it looks like the appropriate tool:
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp